# How to detect page loading error from extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there a way to detect if tab shows 'error page'?

I mean, for example, if user enters any http://non-existing-url.com or just site is unavailable.

Anything similar to Chrome's [webNavigation.onErrorOccured](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onErrorOccurred) event.

If there is no similar event, perhaps there is a way to check Tab http status (200, 404, 502, 0, etc...)?

Comment: The only solution I can think of is to make a parallel [request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/request) and see what the response is there, but then you're making duplicate requests, which could be felt on a slow connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops didn't see this topic. Here is how you can do it look for about:neterror load

from: [mozillaZine :: Detecting “problem loading page” in firefox](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2787683&hilit=+neterror)

have to read the docuri through the webNavigation of the browser. because the window.location is different

anyways the docuri is real nice when an error it happens. it clearly tells you whats wrong with it in the e parameter.
theese are examples of some docuris that load:

> about:neterror?e=dnsNotFound&u=http%3A//www.cu.reporterror%28%27afew/&c=UTF-8&d=Firefox%20can%27t%20find%20the%20server%20at%20www.cu.reporterror%28%27afew.
>
> about:neterror?e=malformedURI&u=about%3Abalk&c=&d=The%20URL%20is%20not%20valid%20and%20cannot%

you can see the first one is dnsNotFound and the second one is malformedURI

```
var listenToPageLoad_IfProblemLoadingPage = function(event) {

    var win = event.originalTarget.defaultView;
    var webnav = win.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Ci.nsIWebNavigation);
    //console.log('webnav:', webnav, 'webnav of selectedtab:', window.gBrowser.webNavigation);
    var docuri = webnav.document.documentURI; //can also try event.originalTarget.linkedBrowser.webNavigation.document.documentURI <<i didnt test this linkedBrowser theory but its gotta be something like that
    var location = win.location + ''; //I add a " + ''" at the end so it makes it a string so we can use string functions like location.indexOf etc

    if (win.frameElement) {
      // Frame within a tab was loaded. win should be the top window of
      // the frameset. If you don't want do anything when frames/iframes
      // are loaded in this web page, uncomment the following line:
      // return;
      // Find the root document:
      //win = win.top;
      if (docuri.indexOf('about:neterror') == 0) {
          Components.utils.reportError('IN FRAME - PROBLEM LOADING PAGE LOADED docuri = "' + docuri + '"');
      }
    } else {
        if (docuri.indexOf('about:neterror') == 0) {
            Components.utils.reportError('IN TAB - PROBLEM LOADING PAGE LOADED docuri = "' + docuri + '"');
        }
    }
}


window.gBrowser.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', listenToPageLoad_IfProblemLoadingPage, false);
```

Comment: Thank you! BTW, maybe you also know a way to detect simple HTTP states for FF tabs? (like 404 or 502, etc...)

Comment: @norlin that's a good question, i dont know off the top of my head but I can look around later, post up anoter question. :)

Comment: Thanks, I already found a way – via [Observer Notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Observer_Notifications)

Comment: @norlin can you post another solution here explaining how you detected the http states?

Comment: This technique can also be used to detect `certerror`: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2930843

Comment: @Noitidart I run the code but I'm getting: `Message: TypeError: window.gBrowser is undefined`.

Comment: @user6875880 you must be in the wrong `window`. Only the browser window, not the "content" window has `gBrowser`. Also this way is deprecated. WebExtensions don't support this. After November this year, using this method will not be possible.

Comment: @Noitidart I am sorry, I did not get what you mean exactly. Can you post a minimal, complete code? I run your code as is, it gives me error. Can you please help?If your code can not be run independently, can you clarify where it should be placed, or edit it so that I can do so?

Comment: @user6875880 - I'm guessing at the errors you got in your last comment. What is currently there is a complete example that works in non-e10s firefox. I just tested pasting it in e10s firefox and it doesnt give errors but it doesnt catch page load as expected. You will need to insert this with a frame script to handle multi process firefox. Are you familiar with frame scripts?

Comment: If you aren't familiar with frame scripts strongly consider webext onErrorOccurred handler - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webNavigation/onErrorOccurred - frame scripts are complicated for new comers. The implementation will likely change as Firefox goes forward, so after you put all the effort in, it can break any moment.

Comment: @Noitidart as I explained to you, I have to work with the SDK. It is not a choice for this piece of work to migrate to WebExt. I am not totally new to SDK, and have done a good amount of work on it. But this particular task is what is new. I have done testing for http interception and tested http responses.

Comment: @Noitidart if it does not catch page loads as expected, then what alternative methods do you suggest?

Comment: @Noitidart perhaps if I tested it in a legacy FF version it works? But, what output shall I expect when I open a page with an error?

Comment: @user6875880 you will see the `Components.utils.reportError` logged to error console. Now to do this in todays firefox you need to run the same script but from a frame script. If webext is not an option you can embed a webext in there and use it just for this part.